# SwiftUI view argument in preview missing argument for parameter 'content' in call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Hi was trying to create a reusable component only with a background gradient, but in the preview is getting an error

this is the component

```
import SwiftUI

struct Patterns<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(
                gradient: Gradient(
                    colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]
                ), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            content
        }
        
    }
}

struct Patterns_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Patterns {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

but the preview looks like this
[image]

Comment: What you've included here compiles and runs fine. But, if you look at your screenshot, you'll see it references code you haven't included in your question.

Comment: Youe're right, te error was in other file that was using that component without the contents argument, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view builder is actually a wrapper for function generating view, so here is fixed variant:

```
struct Patterns<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content     // << here !!

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(
                gradient: Gradient(
                    colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]
                ), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            content()                          // << here !!
        }

    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: Thank you this also help me to understand the view argument, but my error was in other file that was calling this component without the content argument, so the preview was not working, I don't now why, because is only the preview but Xcode needs all working well to render a simp-le preview I think.